# Exibir número que mais se repetiu e sua quantidade

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
def repetido(numeros, count):
    for i in range(len(numeros)):
            count.append(float(numeros[i]))
    for x in range(len(count)):
        aux = count.count(count[x])
        if aux > count:
            repet = count[x]
            contador = count.count(repet)
    print("Valor que mais ocorreu:",repet,"que foi encontrado:",contador,'vezes(es)')

#Programa Principal
entrada = input().split()
n = []
if len(entrada) == 0:
    print('nenhum número foi lido!!!')
else:
    print(repetido(entrada, n))
```

Ao executar o programa e dar enter, sem digitar nenhum número, é exibida a mensagem correta.

Quando digito, por exemplo 1 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 3, ele dá erro e não exibe o que deveria exibir.

Gostaria de saber onde estou errado.

Obrigada!

Comment: `if aux > count`, você está comparando um número inteiro com uma lista. Qual era o objetivo desta linha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, além do `aux > count` como o @Anderson comentou, no seu código

```
else:
    print(repetido(entrada, n))
```

Você pede para printar o retorno da função repetido() mas ela não esta retornanado nada.
Fora essas duas coisas, talvez você poderia simplificar seu código utilizando `mode`.

```
import statistics 
from statistics import mode 

def repetido(numeros):
    return(mode(numeros))

#Programa Principal  
entrada = input().split()
n = []
if len(entrada) == 0:
    print('nenhum número foi lido!!!')
else:
    print('O valor que mais repetiu foi ',repetido(entrada))
```

O mode vai retornar o valor que mais se repete, para ver mais sobre ele da uma olhada na documentação [aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mode)